# Is there a better way to calculate the total value of this invoice model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an Invoice model that has a has_one relationship to another Cart model,

Cart has_many line_items and each line_item has a product with a price attribute.

My approach is the following:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cart, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  def self.total
    sum = 0.0
    Cart.all.each do |c|
      sum += c.total_value
    end
    sum
  end
end
```

And the total_value method on the cart object look something like this:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  def total_value
    sum = 0.0
    line_items.each { |l| sum += l.product.price.present? ? l.product.price * l.quantity : 0.0 }
    sum
  end
end
```

**So my question is, is there a more efficient way to perform the same calculation maybe based on sql queries instead of array manipulation?
And how much efficient it will be?
I also know that my array manipulation is poor, so how can I also achieve the same results in a more ruby way?**

Comment: I think you shoud add `total_value` column to `carts` table and `price` column to `line_items` table.

Comment: I would prefer to calculate them on the fly rather than to store them.

Comment: Why you are calculating Cart.all. I think you should calculate for current cart only.

Comment: I like Andrey's answer below, but to address your comment on array manipulation, check out this blog post that I have come back to over and over when I need a refresher on ruby array manipulation: http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/06/23/using-select-reject-collect-inject-and-detect/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a more efficient way to perform the same calculation maybe
>   based on sql queries instead of array manipulation?

Yes. SQL is so much faster than Ruby that it's hardly comparable:

```
  def self.total
    Cart.joins(line_items: :product)
        .sum('COALESCE(products.pharmacy_price * line_items.quantity, 0.0)')
  end
```

But I think what you might need here is a `total` for a single `cart`, not all `carts` and it will be an *instance method*, not *class instance method*:

```
def total
  self.class
      .joins(cart: { line_items: :product })
      .where(invoices: { id: id })
      .sum('COALESCE(products.pharmacy_price * line_items.quantity, 0.0)')
end
```

So the usage will be `Invoice.first.total`, not `Invoice.total`.

As to `total_value` method - you could write it using calculations on ActiveRecord level, not Ruby, which is again, might be faster:

```
  def total_value
    self.class
        .joins(line_items: :product)
        .where(line_items(cart_id: id))
        .sum('COALESCE(products.pharmacy_price * line_items.quantity, 0.0)')
  end
```

As to

> I also know that my array manipulation is poor, so how can I also
>   achieve the same results in a more ruby way?

You can use [Enumerable#`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
  def total_value
    line_items.inject(0.0) { |sum, l| sum + l.product.pharmacy_price * l.quantity }
  end
```